# Abstracting Delegate registration

Tags: c#, delegates

Is it possible to somehow abstract the following if/else statements, creating a Function or another method, that would make this operation more generic, with less "repeated" code?

I have 2 different classes (Lifecycle and Selection) a 4 Delegate types, like the following example:

```
foreach (Delegate d in delegates)
{
  if (d.GetType ().Equals (typeof (LifeCycle.OnCreatedEvent)))
    Lifecycle.OnCreatedHandlers += (LifeCycle.OnCreatedEvent) d;

  else if (d.GetType ().Equals (typeof (LifeCycle.OnDeletedEvent)))
    LifeCycle.OnDeletedHandlers += (LifeCycle.OnDeletedEvent) d;

  else if (d.GetType ().Equals (typeof (Selection.OnSelectEvent)))
    Selection.OnSelectHandlers += (Selection.OnSelectEvent) d;

  else if (d.GetType ().Equals (typeof (Selection.OnDeselectEvent)))
    Selection.OnDeselectHandlers += (Selection.OnDeselectEvent) d;
}
```

I've considered generics, but I'm not really sure how to abstract the receiving/casting part in a proper, compatible, way where the += operation would be accepted.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Just a small comment - the use of `On*` in your name for events is non-standard. The usual convention is to name the method that raises the event with the `On*`. So the `OnCreatedHandlers` method should raise the `CreatedHandlers` event.

Comment: Why did you put mixed type delegates into one collection?

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
foreach (Delegate d in delegates)
{
    LifeCycle.OnCreatedHandlers  += d as LifeCycle.OnCreatedEvent;
    LifeCycle.OnDeletedHandlers  += d as LifeCycle.OnDeletedEvent;
    Selection.OnSelectHandlers   += d as Selection.OnSelectEvent;
    Selection.OnDeselectHandlers += d as Selection.OnDeselectEvent;
}
```

It's a bit cleaner, and doesn't have the potential runtime issue of testing for and then casting to different types. I believe that `+= null` here will have no effect.